# Java: does Reader.close() close any chained Readers?

Tags: java

Say I do something like:

```
Reader r = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));

... read ...

r.close()
```

Does this close the underlying FileReader (and release the open file handle)?

Comment: Of course if the `BufferedReader` constructor throws, you wont be able to close the underlying `FileReader` (which you can't specify the charset for anyway, so is a bit hopeless itself).

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Yes, calling `close` on the outer most `Reader` is going to be sufficient.

The [Java I/O Streams](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/Streams/ProgIOStreams/) article at the [Sun Developer Network](http://developers.sun.com/) has a section on *Stream Chaining* which says the following:

> ```
> FileOutputStream  fos = new FileOutputStream("myfile.out");   
> CryptOutputStream cos = new CryptOutputStream(fos);   
> GZIPOutputStream  gos = new GZIPOutputStream(cos);
> ```
>
> [...]
>
> [...] when closing chained
>   streams, you only need to close the
>   outermost stream class because the
>   `close()` call is automatically trickled
>   through all the chained classes; in
>   the example above, you would simply
>   call the `close()` method on the
>   `GZIPOutputStream` class.

Therefore, in this case, one would only have to call `close` on the `BufferedReader`.

As [dtsazza already mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1477941/java-does-reader-close-close-any-chained-readers/1477996#1477996), the [Java API Specification](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/) for the [`BufferedReader`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html) class says that the [`BufferedReader.close`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#close()) method will free any underlying resources:

> Closes the stream and releases any system resources associated with it. [...]

So, one can infer that any underlying `Reader`s, even though it may not explicitly say so.

Comment: True (modulo [bugs](http://bugs.sun.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=6266377)) but consider : http://stackoverflow.com/a/3629116/281545. So if `CryptOutputStream` threw  `IOException` in your example shouldn't the caller close `fos` anyway ?

Answer (score 4):

According to [the documentation](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/Reader.html#close()), it merely "releases any system resources associated with [the reader]".  Whether a Reader closes any nested readers is a matter of the specific class' implementation.

In the specific example you mentioned - yes, a `BufferedReader` will always close the nested reader.  But while this *usually* happens, this doesn't necessarily mean that *all* implementations of the `Reader` interface that have some sort of nested reader will propagate a `close()` call through to them - you'd need to check the documentation of that specific class to find out.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. It does.  I found this out when using it for sockets.

[My Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/484925/does-closing-the-bufferedreader-printwriter-close-the-socket-connection)

Basically you just can't close it until you are done with the parent.  In the case of sockets this will actually close your socket.  :-(

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is the Decorator pattern.