# How to append text to an existing file in Java?

Tags: java, file-io, io, text-files

I need to append text repeatedly to an existing file in Java. How do I do that?

Answer (score 925, accepted):

Are you doing this for logging purposes?  If so there are [several libraries for this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_logging_framework). Two of the most popular are [Log4j](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/) and [Logback](http://logback.qos.ch/).

### Java 7+

For a one-time task, the [Files class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html) makes this easy:

```
try {
    Files.write(Paths.get("myfile.txt"), "the text".getBytes(), StandardOpenOption.APPEND);
}catch (IOException e) {
    //exception handling left as an exercise for the reader
}
```

**Careful**: The above approach will throw a `NoSuchFileException` if the file does not already exist. It also does not append a newline automatically (which you often want when appending to a text file). Another approach is to pass both `CREATE` and `APPEND` options, which will create the file first if it doesn't already exist:

```
private void write(final String s) throws IOException {
    Files.writeString(
        Path.of(System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir"), "filename.txt"),
        s + System.lineSeparator(),
        CREATE, APPEND
    );
}
```

However, if you will be writing to the same file many times, the above snippets must open and close the file on the disk many times, which is a slow operation. In this case, a `BufferedWriter` is faster:

```
try(FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("myfile.txt", true);
    BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
    PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(bw))
{
    out.println("the text");
    //more code
    out.println("more text");
    //more code
} catch (IOException e) {
    //exception handling left as an exercise for the reader
}
```

**Notes:**

- The second parameter to the `FileWriter` constructor will tell it to append to the file, rather than writing a new file. (If the file does not exist, it will be created.)
- Using a `BufferedWriter` is recommended for an expensive writer (such as `FileWriter`).
- Using a `PrintWriter` gives you access to `println` syntax that you're probably used to from `System.out`.
- But the `BufferedWriter` and `PrintWriter` wrappers are not strictly necessary.

---

### Older Java

```
try {
    PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("myfile.txt", true)));
    out.println("the text");
    out.close();
} catch (IOException e) {
    //exception handling left as an exercise for the reader
}
```

---

### Exception Handling

If you need robust exception handling for older Java, it gets very verbose:

```
FileWriter fw = null;
BufferedWriter bw = null;
PrintWriter out = null;
try {
    fw = new FileWriter("myfile.txt", true);
    bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
    out = new PrintWriter(bw);
    out.println("the text");
    out.close();
} catch (IOException e) {
    //exception handling left as an exercise for the reader
}
finally {
    try {
        if(out != null)
            out.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        //exception handling left as an exercise for the reader
    }
    try {
        if(bw != null)
            bw.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        //exception handling left as an exercise for the reader
    }
    try {
        if(fw != null)
            fw.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        //exception handling left as an exercise for the reader
    }
}
```

Comment: You should either use java7 try-with-resources or put the close() in a finally block, in order to make sure that the file is closed in case of exception

Comment: Lets imagine that `new BufferedWriter(...)` throws an exception; Will the `FileWriter` be closed ? I guess that it will not be closed, because the `close()` method (in normal conditions) will be invoked on the `out` object, which int this case will not be initialized - so actually the `close()` method will not be invoked -> the file will be opened, but will not be closed. So IMHO the `try` statement should look like this 

`try(FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("myFile.txt")){
Print writer = new ....//code goes here
}`

And he should `flush()` the writer before exiting the `try` block!!!

Comment: it's not work for me. in destination file, there is one "test" and many empty space

Comment: If you use Java 7+, then why not use a simple `Files.write` instead of a PrintWriter of a BufferedWriter of a FileWriter?

Comment: This answer fails to correctly handle exceptions. See @Emily's [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18746974/603516) for proper way.

Comment: Why is FileWriter treated like expensive writer?

Comment: @RadijatoR Because it has to do disk I/O operations. In the [JavaDoc for BufferedWriter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/BufferedWriter.html), it says "In general, a Writer sends its output immediately to the underlying character or byte stream. Unless prompt output is required, it is advisable to wrap a BufferedWriter around any Writer whose write() operations may be costly, such as FileWriters and OutputStreamWriters"

Comment: This can be done in one line of code. Hope this helps :)

Files.write(Paths.get(fileName), msg.getBytes(), StandardOpenOption.APPEND);

Comment: The `File` and filename-based constructors of `PrintWriter` mention that they buffer automatically. But when a `PrintWriter` wraps another `Writer`, there is no comment in the docs on whether it adds another layer of buffering or not. Given the ambiguity, it seems best to include a `BufferedWriter` explicitly, as in this answer.

Comment: @Decoded your suggested edit was a syntax error. `out` is only defined in the `try` block. In the `finally` block it does not exist. You would have to move the declaration of `out` out of the `try` block. This is exactly the problem that the Java 7+ syntax resolves. As I've noted, I've left exception handling for the reader; I think it's beyond the scope of this answer.

Comment: You should close only the out variable! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/484925/does-closing-the-bufferedreader-printwriter-close-the-socket-connection

Comment: A couple of possible "gotchas" with the Java 7 method: (1) If the file doesn't already exist, `StandardOpenOption.APPEND` won't create it - kind of like a silent failure as it won't throw an exception either. (2) Using `.getBytes()` will mean there is no return character before or after the appended text. Have added an [alternative answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1625234#44301865) to address these.

Comment: @SteveChambers Thanks for the input. I couldn't believe that append mode does not create the file if it does not exist, so I had to try it to confirm. Not sure what they were thinking there... I found that it does actually throw an exception, but if you copy/paste my code and leave the `catch` block blank, then you don't see it. I've updated my answer to reflect these issues and I added a link to your answer.

Comment: Is it safe to use the faster, buffered operations?  I'm trying to log something that happens right before a crash, and I need to make sure the file is going to get written.

Comment: @Michael when the buffered writer is closed, it will write whatever is in the buffer. Or you can explicitly call `flush()` to force it to flush its buffer (writing the contents) immediately.

Comment: "If you need robust exception handling for older Java, it gets very verbose." If by "verbose" you mean "a horrifying abomination".

Comment: This works in Scala as well:     try {
      Files.write(Paths.get("myfile.txt"), "the text".getBytes(), StandardOpenOption.APPEND)
    } catch {
      case ioe: IOException => { println("IOException thrown!") }
      case e: Exception => println("Non-IOException thrown!")
    }

Comment: The `Files.writeString()` and `Path.of()` are both no symbol error, is it a typo?

Comment: @Weekend it worked when i wrote the answer but i haven't done any serious java development in quite a long time 

Comment: "Log4j" Haha, that part certainly didn't age well.

Answer (score 201):

You can use `fileWriter` with a flag set to `true` , for appending.

```
try
{
    String filename= "MyFile.txt";
    FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(filename,true); //the true will append the new data
    fw.write("add a line\n");//appends the string to the file
    fw.close();
}
catch(IOException ioe)
{
    System.err.println("IOException: " + ioe.getMessage());
}
```

Comment: `close` should be placed in `finally` block just like shown in [@etech's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15053443/1393766) in case exception would be thrown between creation of FileWriter and invoking close.

Comment: Good answer, although its better to use System.getProperty( "line.separator" ) for a new line rather than "\n".

Comment: @Decoded I've rolled back your edit on this answer, as it does not compile.

Comment: @Kip, What was the issue? I must have entered a "typo".

Comment: @Decoded you had `fw.close()` in a finally block, without a nested try/catch (`.close()` can throw `IOException`)

Comment: How bout try-with-resources?

```try(FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(filename,true)){
// Whatever
}catch(IOException ex){
ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 75):

Shouldn't all of the answers here with try/catch blocks have the .close() pieces contained in a finally block?

Example for marked answer:

```
PrintWriter out = null;
try {
    out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("writePath", true)));
    out.println("the text");
} catch (IOException e) {
    System.err.println(e);
} finally {
    if (out != null) {
        out.close();
    }
}
```

Also, as of Java 7, you can use a [try-with-resources statement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html). No finally block is required for closing the declared resource(s) because it is handled automatically, and is also less verbose:

```
try(PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("writePath", true)))) {
    out.println("the text");
} catch (IOException e) {
    System.err.println(e);
}
```

Comment: When `out` goes out of scope, it is automatically closed when it gets garbage-collected, right?  In your example with the `finally` block, I think you actually need another nested try/catch around `out.close()` if I remember correctly.  The Java 7 solution is pretty slick! (I haven't been doing any Java dev since Java 6, so I was unfamiliar with that change.)

Comment: @Kip Nope, going out-of-scope does nothing in Java. The file will get closed at some random time in the future. (probably when the program closes)

Comment: @etech Will the second approach need the `flush` method?

Comment: This is not an answer to the question, it is a comment on the other answers, and the code provided does not compile.

Comment: @syfantid No. Close calls flush.

Answer (score 52):

Using Apache Commons 2.1:

```
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.util.FileUtils;

FileUtils.writeStringToFile(file, "String to append", true);
```

Comment: Oh, thank you. I was amused by the complexity of all other answers. I really do not get why people like to complicate their (developer) life.

Comment: The problem with this approach is that it opens and closes the output stream every single time. Depending on what and how often you write to your file, this could result in a ridiculous overhead.

Comment: @Buffalo is right. But you can always use StringBuilder for building large chunks (that are worth writing) before writing them to file.

Comment: @KonstantinK but then all the content you need to write is loaded into memory.

Answer (score 37):

Slightly expanding on [Kip's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1625234#1625263),
here is a simple Java 7+ method to append a **new line** to a file, **creating it if it doesn't already exist**:

```
try {
    final Path path = Paths.get("path/to/filename.txt");
    Files.write(path, Arrays.asList("New line to append"), StandardCharsets.UTF_8,
        Files.exists(path) ? StandardOpenOption.APPEND : StandardOpenOption.CREATE);
} catch (final IOException ioe) {
    // Add your own exception handling...
}
```

**Further notes:**

1. The above uses the [`Files.write`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#write(java.nio.file.Path,%20java.lang.Iterable,%20java.nio.charset.Charset,%20java.nio.file.OpenOption...)) overload that writes *lines* of text to a file (i.e. similar to a `println` command). To just write text to the end (i.e. similar to a `print` command), an alternative [`Files.write`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#write(java.nio.file.Path,%20byte%5B%5D,%20java.nio.file.OpenOption...)) overload can be used, passing in a byte array (e.g. `"mytext".getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)`).
2. The `CREATE` option will only work if the specified directory already exists - if it doesn't, a `NoSuchFileException` is thrown. If required, the following code could be added after setting `path` to create the directory structure:

   ```
   Path pathParent = path.getParent();
   if (!Files.exists(pathParent)) {
       Files.createDirectories(pathParent);
   }
   ```

Comment: Do you need to check if the file exists? I thought`.CREATE` does the job for you.

Comment: If `.CREATE` is used when the file already exists it silently fails to append anything - no exception is thrown but the existing file contents remain unchanged.

Comment: Using `APPEND` + `CREATE` works perfectly, no check necessary:
`Files.write(Paths.get("test.log"), (Instant.now().toString() + "\r\n").getBytes(), StandardOpenOption.CREATE, StandardOpenOption.APPEND);`

Answer (score 22):

### Make sure the stream gets properly closed in all scenarios.

It's a bit alarming how many of these answers leave the file handle open in case of an error. The answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/15053443/2498188 is on the money but only because `BufferedWriter()` cannot throw. If it could then an exception would leave the `FileWriter` object open.

A more general way of doing this that doesn't care if `BufferedWriter()` can throw:

```
  PrintWriter out = null;
  BufferedWriter bw = null;
  FileWriter fw = null;
  try{
     fw = new FileWriter("outfilename", true);
     bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
     out = new PrintWriter(bw);
     out.println("the text");
  }
  catch( IOException e ){
     // File writing/opening failed at some stage.
  }
  finally{
     try{
        if( out != null ){
           out.close(); // Will close bw and fw too
        }
        else if( bw != null ){
           bw.close(); // Will close fw too
        }
        else if( fw != null ){
           fw.close();
        }
        else{
           // Oh boy did it fail hard! :3
        }
     }
     catch( IOException e ){
        // Closing the file writers failed for some obscure reason
     }
  }
```

### Edit:

As of Java 7, the recommended way is to use "try with resources" and let the JVM deal with it:

```
  try(    FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("outfilename", true);
          BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
          PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(bw)){
     out.println("the text");
  }  
  catch( IOException e ){
      // File writing/opening failed at some stage.
  }
```

Comment: +1 for correct ARM with Java 7. Here is good question about this tricky theme: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12552863/correct-idiom-for-managing-multiple-chained-resources-in-try-with-resources-bloc.

Comment: Hmm, for some reason `PrintWriter.close()` is not declared as `throws IOException` in [the docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html#close%28%29). Looking at its [source](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/io/PrintWriter.java.html), the `close()` method, indeed, cannot throw `IOException`, because it catches it from the underlying stream, and sets a flag. So if you're working on the code for the next Space Shuttle or an X-ray dose metering system, you should use `PrintWriter.checkError()` after attempting to `out.close()`. This should really have been documented.

Comment: If we're going to be super paranoid about closing, each of those `XX.close()` should be in its own try/catch, right? For example, `out.close()` could throw an exception, in which case `bw.close()` and `fw.close()` would never get called, and `fw` is the one that is most critical to close.

Comment: ’ButferedWriter’ *can* throw.

Answer (score 13):

In Java-7 it also can be done such kind:

```
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.nio.file.StandardOpenOption;
```

//---------------------

```
Path filePath = Paths.get("someFile.txt");
if (!Files.exists(filePath)) {
    Files.createFile(filePath);
}
Files.write(filePath, "Text to be added".getBytes(), StandardOpenOption.APPEND);
```

Comment: What are the imports required? Which library do these things use?

Comment: The exists/create part is literally a waste of time and space.

Answer (score 13):

**java 7+**

In my humble opinion since I am fan of plain java, I would suggest something that it is a combination of the aforementioned answers. Maybe I am late for the party. Here is the code:

```
 String sampleText = "test" +  System.getProperty("line.separator");
 Files.write(Paths.get(filePath), sampleText.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8), 
 StandardOpenOption.CREATE, StandardOpenOption.APPEND);
```

If the file doesn't exist, it creates it and if already exists it appends the 
*sampleText* to the existing file. Using this, saves you from adding unnecessary libs to your classpath.

Answer (score 9):

This can be done in one line of code. Hope this helps :)

```
Files.write(Paths.get(fileName), msg.getBytes(), StandardOpenOption.APPEND);
```

Comment: its may be not enough:) better version is 
Files.write(Paths.get(fileName), msg.getBytes(), StandardOpenOption.APPEND, StandardOpenOption.CREATE);

Answer (score 5):

I just add small detail:

```
    new FileWriter("outfilename", true)
```

2.nd parameter (true) is a feature (or, interface) called **appendable** (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Appendable.html). It is responsible for being able to add some content to the end of particular file/stream. This interface is implemented since Java 1.5. Each object (i.e. *BufferedWriter, CharArrayWriter, CharBuffer, FileWriter, FilterWriter, LogStream, OutputStreamWriter, PipedWriter, PrintStream, PrintWriter, StringBuffer, StringBuilder, StringWriter, Writer*) with this interface can be used for adding content

In other words, you can add some content to your gzipped file, or some http process

Answer (score 5):

Using java.nio.[Files](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html) along with java.nio.file.[StandardOpenOption](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/StandardOpenOption.html)

```
    PrintWriter out = null;
    BufferedWriter bufWriter;

    try{
        bufWriter =
            Files.newBufferedWriter(
                Paths.get("log.txt"),
                Charset.forName("UTF8"),
                StandardOpenOption.WRITE, 
                StandardOpenOption.APPEND,
                StandardOpenOption.CREATE);
        out = new PrintWriter(bufWriter, true);
    }catch(IOException e){
        //Oh, no! Failed to create PrintWriter
    }

    //After successful creation of PrintWriter
    out.println("Text to be appended");

    //After done writing, remember to close!
    out.close();
```

This creates a `BufferedWriter` using Files, which accepts `StandardOpenOption` parameters, and an auto-flushing `PrintWriter` from the resultant `BufferedWriter`. `PrintWriter`'s `println()` method, can then be called to write to the file.

The `StandardOpenOption` parameters used in this code: opens the file for writing, only appends to the file, and creates the file if it does not exist.

`Paths.get("path here")` can be replaced with `new File("path here").toPath()`.
And `Charset.forName("charset name")` can be modified to accommodate the desired `Charset`.

Answer (score 4):

Sample, using Guava:

```
File to = new File("C:/test/test.csv");

for (int i = 0; i < 42; i++) {
    CharSequence from = "some string" + i + "\n";
    Files.append(from, to, Charsets.UTF_8);
}
```

Comment: This is horrible advice. You open a stream to the file 42 times instead of once.

Comment: @xehpuk well, it depends. 42 is still ok, if it makes code much more readable. 42k wouldn't be acceptable.

Answer (score 4):

```
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("File_Name", true);
fos.write(data);
```

the true allows to append the data in the existing file. If we will write

```
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("File_Name");
```

It will overwrite the existing file. So go for first approach.

Answer (score 4):

```
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

public class Writer {


    public static void main(String args[]){
        doWrite("output.txt","Content to be appended to file");
    }

    public static void doWrite(String filePath,String contentToBeAppended){

       try(
            FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(filePath, true);
            BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
            PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(bw)
          )
          {
            out.println(contentToBeAppended);
          }  
        catch( IOException e ){
        // File writing/opening failed at some stage.
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: The above is just a quick example implementation of the solution presented [At this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1625234/how-to-append-text-to-an-existing-file-in-java/18746974#18746974). So you can copy and and run the code and immediately see how it works, be sure that the output.out file is in the same directory as the Writer.java file

Answer (score 3):

```
    String str;
    String path = "C:/Users/...the path..../iin.txt"; // you can input also..i created this way :P

    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(path, true));

    try 
    {
       while(true)
        {
            System.out.println("Enter the text : ");
            str = br.readLine();
            if(str.equalsIgnoreCase("exit"))
                break;
            else
                pw.println(str);
        }
    } 
    catch (Exception e) 
    {
        //oh noes!
    }
    finally
    {
        pw.close();         
    }
```

this will do what you intend for..

Answer (score 3):

You can also try this :

```
JFileChooser c= new JFileChooser();
c.showOpenDialog(c);
File write_file = c.getSelectedFile();
String Content = "Writing into file"; //what u would like to append to the file



try 
{
    RandomAccessFile raf = new RandomAccessFile(write_file, "rw");
    long length = raf.length();
    //System.out.println(length);
    raf.setLength(length + 1); //+ (integer value) for spacing
    raf.seek(raf.length());
    raf.writeBytes(Content);
    raf.close();
} 
catch (Exception e) {
    //any exception handling method of ur choice
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Better to use try-with-resources then all that pre-java 7 finally business

```
static void appendStringToFile(Path file, String s) throws IOException  {
    try (BufferedWriter out = Files.newBufferedWriter(file, StandardCharsets.UTF_8, StandardOpenOption.APPEND)) {
        out.append(s);
        out.newLine();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Try with bufferFileWriter.append, it works with me.

```
FileWriter fileWriter;
try {
    fileWriter = new FileWriter(file,true);
    BufferedWriter bufferFileWriter = new BufferedWriter(fileWriter);
    bufferFileWriter.append(obj.toJSONString());
    bufferFileWriter.newLine();
    bufferFileWriter.close();
} catch (IOException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(JsonTest.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}
```

Comment: what is obj.toJSONString() here?

Comment: @BhaskaraArani It's just a string, he put an example of a JSON object converted to a string but the idea is that it could be any string.

Comment: It is the ’true` parameter that is doing the appending here, not ’BufferedWriter`.

Answer (score 3):

If we are using Java 7 and above and also know the content to be added (appended) to the file we can make use of [newBufferedWriter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#newBufferedWriter(java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.charset.Charset,%20java.nio.file.OpenOption...)) method in NIO package.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Path FILE_PATH = Paths.get("C:/temp", "temp.txt");
    String text = "\n Welcome to Java 8";

    //Writing to the file temp.txt
    try (BufferedWriter writer = Files.newBufferedWriter(FILE_PATH, StandardCharsets.UTF_8, StandardOpenOption.APPEND)) {
        writer.write(text);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

There are few points to note:

1. It is always a good habit to specify charset encoding and for that we have constant in class `StandardCharsets`.
2. The code uses `try-with-resource` statement in which resources are automatically closed after the try.

Though OP has not asked but just in case we want to search for lines having some specific keyword e.g. `confidential` we can make use of stream APIs in Java:

```
//Reading from the file the first line which contains word "confidential"
try {
    Stream<String> lines = Files.lines(FILE_PATH);
    Optional<String> containsJava = lines.filter(l->l.contains("confidential")).findFirst();
    if(containsJava.isPresent()){
        System.out.println(containsJava.get());
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: a caveat: when using BufferedWriter `write(String string)` if one expects a new line after each string written, `newLine()` should be called

Answer (score 2):

```
FileOutputStream stream = new FileOutputStream(path, true);
try {

    stream.write(

        string.getBytes("UTF-8") // Choose your encoding.

    );

} finally {
    stream.close();
}
```

Then catch an IOException somewhere upstream.

Answer (score 2):

Create a function anywhere in your project and simply call that function where ever you need it.

Guys you got to remember that you guys are calling active threads that you are not calling asynchronously and since it would likely be a good 5 to 10 pages to get it done right.
Why not spend more time on your project and forget about writing anything already written.
Properly

```
    //Adding a static modifier would make this accessible anywhere in your app

    public Logger getLogger()
    {
       return java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger("MyLogFileName");
    }
    //call the method anywhere and append what you want to log 
    //Logger class will take care of putting timestamps for you
    //plus the are ansychronously done so more of the 
    //processing power will go into your application

    //from inside a function body in the same class ...{...

    getLogger().log(Level.INFO,"the text you want to append");

    ...}...
    /*********log file resides in server root log files********/
```

three lines of code two really since the third actually appends text. :P

Answer (score 2):

> Library

```
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
```

> Code

```
public void append()
{
    try
    {
        String path = "D:/sample.txt";

        File file = new File(path);

        FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter(file,true);

        BufferedWriter bufferFileWriter  = new BufferedWriter(fileWriter);

        fileWriter.append("Sample text in the file to append");

        bufferFileWriter.close();

        System.out.println("User Registration Completed");

    }catch(Exception ex)
    {
        System.out.println(ex);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I might suggest the [apache commons project](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-functor/examples.html). This project already provides a framework for doing what you need (i.e. flexible filtering of collections).

Answer (score 1):

This code will fulifil your need:

```
   FileWriter fw=new FileWriter("C:\\file.json",true);
   fw.write("ssssss");
   fw.close();
```

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileWriter.html#FileWriter(java.io.File,%20boolean)

Comment: @WestCoastProjects No it won’t, it will append.

Answer (score 1):

In case you want to **ADD SOME TEXT IN SPECIFIC LINES** you can first read the whole file, append the text wherever you want and then overwrite everything like in the code below:

```
public static void addDatatoFile(String data1, String data2){


    String fullPath = "/home/user/dir/file.csv";

    File dir = new File(fullPath);
    List<String> l = new LinkedList<String>();

    try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(dir))) {
        String line;
        int count = 0;

        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            if(count == 1){
                //add data at the end of second line                    
                line += data1;
            }else if(count == 2){
                //add other data at the end of third line
                line += data2;
            }
            l.add(line);
            count++;
        }
        br.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }       
    createFileFromList(l, dir);
}

public static void createFileFromList(List<String> list, File f){

    PrintWriter writer;
    try {
        writer = new PrintWriter(f, "UTF-8");
        for (String d : list) {
            writer.println(d.toString());
        }
        writer.close();             
    } catch (FileNotFoundException | UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The following method let's you append text to some file:

```
private void appendToFile(String filePath, String text)
{
    PrintWriter fileWriter = null;

    try
    {
        fileWriter = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(
                filePath, true)));

        fileWriter.println(text);
    } catch (IOException ioException)
    {
        ioException.printStackTrace();
    } finally
    {
        if (fileWriter != null)
        {
            fileWriter.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Alternatively using [`FileUtils`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html):

```
public static void appendToFile(String filePath, String text) throws IOException
{
    File file = new File(filePath);

    if(!file.exists())
    {
        file.createNewFile();
    }

    String fileContents = FileUtils.readFileToString(file);

    if(file.length() != 0)
    {
        fileContents = fileContents.concat(System.lineSeparator());
    }

    fileContents = fileContents.concat(text);

    FileUtils.writeStringToFile(file, fileContents);
}
```

It is not efficient but works fine. Line breaks are handled correctly and a new file is created if one didn't exist yet.

Comment: The exists/create part is literally a waste of time and space.

Answer (score 0):

**For JDK version >= 7**

You can utilise this simple method which appends the given content to the specified file:

```
void appendToFile(String filePath, String content) {
  try (FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(filePath, true)) {
    fw.write(content + System.lineSeparator());
  } catch (IOException e) { 
    // TODO handle exception
  }
}
```

We are constructing a [FileWriter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/FileWriter.html#FileWriter-java.io.File-boolean-) object in append mode.

Answer (score -1):

My answer:

```
JFileChooser chooser= new JFileChooser();
chooser.showOpenDialog(chooser);
File file = chooser.getSelectedFile();
String Content = "What you want to append to file";

try 
{
    RandomAccessFile random = new RandomAccessFile(file, "rw");
    long length = random.length();
    random.setLength(length + 1);
    random.seek(random.length());
    random.writeBytes(Content);
    random.close();
} 
catch (Exception exception) {
    //exception handling
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
/**********************************************************************
 * it will write content to a specified  file
 * 
 * @param keyString
 * @throws IOException
 *********************************************************************/
public static void writeToFile(String keyString,String textFilePAth) throws IOException {
    // For output to file
    File a = new File(textFilePAth);

    if (!a.exists()) {
        a.createNewFile();
    }
    FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(a.getAbsoluteFile(), true);
    BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
    bw.append(keyString);
    bw.newLine();
    bw.close();
}// end of writeToFile()
```

Comment: The exists/create part is literally a waste of time and space.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the follong code to append the content in the file:

```
 String fileName="/home/shriram/Desktop/Images/"+"test.txt";
  FileWriter fw=new FileWriter(fileName,true);    
  fw.write("here will be you content to insert or append in file");    
  fw.close(); 
  FileWriter fw1=new FileWriter(fileName,true);    
 fw1.write("another content will be here to be append in the same file");    
 fw1.close();
```

Answer (score -1):

1.7 Approach:

```
void appendToFile(String filePath, String content) throws IOException{

    Path path = Paths.get(filePath);

    try (BufferedWriter writer = 
            Files.newBufferedWriter(path, 
                    StandardOpenOption.APPEND)) {
        writer.newLine();
        writer.append(content);
    }

    /*
    //Alternative:
    try (BufferedWriter bWriter = 
            Files.newBufferedWriter(path, 
                    StandardOpenOption.WRITE, StandardOpenOption.APPEND);
            PrintWriter pWriter = new PrintWriter(bWriter)
            ) {
        pWriter.println();//to have println() style instead of newLine();   
        pWriter.append(content);//Also, bWriter.append(content);
    }*/
}
```