# Socket timeout and cancellation

Tags: java, android, sockets

I have the following code running in AsyncTask:

```
    socket = new Socket(host, Integer.parseInt(port));
```

In the case when host name is correct, but there is no socket server listening on the port, this line may work several minutes before throwing exception. Can I set communication timeout? Also, is it possible to stop this process - currently it doesn't react to AsyncTask.cancel call.

Comment: That's not correct. It may take up to about seventy seconds *if the host doesn't respond at all*, which would only happen if there was a network discontinuity or a firewall in the way. If the host responds, you will get either a connection or a 'connection refused' within a second or two.

Comment: Non-existing host is handled within 1-2 seconds. BTW, does your note help to solve the problem (which is already solved)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create the socket with the no parameters contructor like this:

```
socket = new Socket();
```

Then use

```
socket.connect(remoteAddress, timeout);
```

See http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/Socket.html for more information.

-- Update --

I didn't notice originally that you asked about how to cancel the socket connection.
While I'm not real familiar with socket programming it looks like you would do this:

1. Call cancel on the asynctask as you seem to already have tried.
2. Override/Implement [onCancelled](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#onCancelled%28Result%29) method for the async task. In the implementation, you will need to use your reference to the socket (make it a class instance variable), and call the close() method of the socket. Be sure to read up on closing a socket and make sure you're handling the exceptions for the input/output stream appropriately so your app doesn't crash. Checkout [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3428127/close-java-socket) question for more info on closing sockets.

Answer (score 1):

You have to create a socket first and then use below method in it.

```
Socket client=new Socket();   
client.connect(new InetSocketAddress(hostip,port_num),connection_time_out);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
Socket soc = null;
while(soc == null){
    try{
        soc = new Socket("x.x.x.x", portNumber);
    }
    catch(Exception ex){
    }
}
```

Since:

```
socket.connect(remoteAddress, timeout)
```

Is notoriously unreliable, you could code your own version of timeout. The code I wrote, waits for a connection infinitely, but you can very easily introduce a timer.