# Excel file gets corrupted while converting byte[] to excel

Tags: java

In my application, I am getting excel file in chunks as input. Let say, if excel file size is 20 MB then I will get 4 chunks, where each chunk(byte[]) is of 5MB. I am writing each chunk (byte[]) into temp file (with no extension). I am using this temp file to regenerate actual excel file which is sent to me in multiple chunks. My requirement is that generated excel file must be same as the excel file which I got in chunks.

**Sample Code:**

1. Reading excel file, converting into chunks and writing those chunks to temp file.

   public static void readExcelFileBytes(String srcFile) throws IOException {

   ```
   File file = new File(srcFile);

   FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);

   byte[] buf = new byte[1024 * 5]; // 5KB
   int totalNoOfBytes = 0;
   try {
       for (int readNum; (readNum = fis.read(buf)) != -1;) {               
           appendByteArrayToTempFile(buf);
       }
   } catch (IOException ex) {
       ex.printStackTrace();
   }
   System.out.println("Read: Total Size Bytes" + totalNoOfBytes);

   }

   public static boolean appendByteArrayToTempFile(byte[] byteArray) {

   boolean result = false;
   BufferedWriter writeout = null;
   File bodfile = null;
   FileOutputStream out = null;
   try {
       bodfile = new File("C://tempFile");
       out = new FileOutputStream(bodfile, true);
       out.write(byteArray);           

       result = true;

   } catch (IOException ex) {
       ex.printStackTrace();
   } finally {
       try {
           //writeout.close();
           out.close();
       } catch (IOException ex) {
           ex.printStackTrace();
       }
   }
   return result;
   }
   ```
2. Using temp byte[] to regenerate excel file.

public static void tempToFile(String srcFilePath) throws IOException{

```
   File file = new File("C://tempFile");

   FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);

   ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
   byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
   try {
       for (int readNum; (readNum = fis.read(buf)) != -1;) {
           bos.write(buf, 0, readNum); //no doubt here is 0                

       }
   } catch (IOException ex) {
       ex.printStackTrace();
   }
   byte[] bytes = bos.toByteArray();

   // Create source file from Temp's byte array
   FileOutputStream fileOuputStream =  new FileOutputStream(srcFilePath); 
   fileOuputStream.write(bytes);
   fileOuputStream.flush();
   fileOuputStream.close();
}
```

**Issue:**

public static void main(String s[]) throws IOException {

```
    // XLS POC
    readExcelFileBytes("C://Input.xlsx");
    tempToFile("C://Output.xlsx");

}
```

But when excel file is generated using temp file byte[], it gets currepted. Can somebody help me whether I am following proper way to re-generate excel file using temp file byte[]?

Comment: Why do you _reopen_ the temp file each time? Also, you don't `.flush()` after having written into the temp file.

Comment: Do a bytewise comparison of the input and output files; this will tell you where the first error is.  That should hopefully be a big clue.

Comment: @fge You don't need to flush before closing.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik output streams are buffered

Comment: @fge So? Do you have an example of a broken `OutputStream` implementation whose `close` method doesn't flush automatically? `FileOutputStream` is not such an example in any case.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik oh, plenty: sockets, for instance. In any case, it never hurts, so you'd better `.flush()`... If it is a noop, good. If it isn't, you have saved you day.

Comment: @fge You mixed it up... if you close the output stream retrieved from `Socket.getOutputStream()`, you'll never lose a byte. If, on the other hand, you close the socket without previously closing the output stream, only then you may experience loss (probably not even then, though).

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik "if you close the output stream retrieved from Socket.getOutputStream(), you'll never lose a byte" <-- wrong. Examples are plenty on SO where people `.write()` to it without flusing afterwards and wonder why the client hasn't received anything. OK, nevermind, do as you please and I'll keep flushing around in any case ;)

Comment: @fge For a detailed account of the flushing behavior of socket output streams, see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3428934/1103872). Main point: `close` guarantees that everything is queued into the OS-level send buffer, but the actual sending happens asynchronously (as always). This asynchrony is the only potential pitfall.

Comment: @ Oli: Can you please suggest the way for bytewise comparison?

Comment: @fge Flushing before closing fits squarely within the category of [Cargo Cult Programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cargo_cult_programming).

Answer (score 2):

Wouldn't it be better to use an existing library which copies files automatically?

One of that libraries is Jakarta Commons

- [org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils](http://commons.apache.org/io/api-release/org/apache/commons/io/IOUtils.html)
- [org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils](http://commons.apache.org/io/api-release/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html)

It's been used by hundreds of developers; it is very well tested and will definitely help you with file copy task.

**EDIT**

If you are getting corrupted files, the best way to check if your file copy mechanism (either your own one of from any library) is working fine it to check the input and output file checksum. Input file checksum should be the same as output file checksum.

Assuming your input `java.io.File` is `input` and output `File` is `output` your code checking files checksum could look as follows:

```js
long inputChecksum = FileUtils.checksumCRC32(input);

// if there is an issue with file copy IOException is thrown
FileUtils.copyFile(input, output);

// inputChecksum should be the same as outputChecksum
long outputChecksum = FileUtils.checksumCRC32(output);
```

Comment: Thanks tom for your reply. I even tried this code `FileUtils.writeByteArrayToFile(new File(srcFilePath), bytes)` in place of `FileOutputStream fileOuputStream = new FileOutputStream(srcFilePath); fileOuputStream.write(bytes); fileOuputStream.flush(); fileOuputStream.close();` in **tempToFile(String srcFilePath)** method. But no luck :(

Comment: Where FileUtils is from Apache Common.

Comment: `FileUtils` class is in `org.apache.commons.io` package. You can download the latest version of the library (2.4) from here: http://commons.apache.org/io/download_io.cgi

Comment: Yes, I tried with org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils as well. But, did not succeed.

Comment: @Narendra, when you say "no succeed" do you mean that your output file is still corrupted?

Answer (score 2):

This piece of code is definitely wrong:

```
for (int readNum; (readNum = fis.read(buf)) != -1;) {               
    appendByteArrayToTempFile(buf);
}
```

You ignore the number of bytes that were actually read into `buf` and unconditionally write out the whole `buf` every time. You need

```
for (int readNum; (readNum = fis.read(buf)) != -1;) {               
    appendByteArrayToTempFile(buf, readNum);
}
```

and implement `appendByteArrayToTempFile` accordingly.

Comment: Hi Marko, thanks for your reply. I used same code for images that is working fine. Below code is used to re-generate image from temp byte[] in **tempToFile(String srcFilePath)** method: `BufferedImage InputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes); BufferedImage bImageFromConvert = ImageIO.read(in); ImageIO.write(bImageFromConvert, "png", new File(srcImagePath));` instead of this code `// Create source file from Temp's byte array FileOutputStream fileOuputStream = new FileOutputStream(srcFilePath); fileOuputStream.write(bytes); fileOuputStream.flush(); fileOuputStream.close(); `