# Best mechanism to close java sockets?

Tags: java, sockets

I have followed this link [What is the difference between closing Input/OutputStream and closing Socket directly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3428127/what-is-the-difference-between-closing-input-outputstream-and-closing-socket-dir) on how to close my java sockets. The problem after doing some jmap histo we find the number of sockets keep growing and but resultsets fluctuates. Snippet of my codes is as below.

```
BoneCP connectionPool = null;
  class ConnectionHandler implements Runnable {
    private Socket receivedSocketConn1;
    ConnectionHandler(Socket receivedSocketConn1) {
      this.receivedSocketConn1=receivedSocketConn1;
    }
    Connection dbconn = null;
    public void run() { // etc
     BufferedWriter writeBuffer = null;
     BufferedReader readBuffer = null;
     String capturedMessage="";
     try{
        dbconn = connectionPool.getConnection();
        dbconn.setAutoCommit(false);
        while ((nextChar=readBuffer.read()) != -1){          
          capturedMessage += (char) nextChar;
          if (nextChar == '*')
          {
           try{
                //all queries here.
                //for insert query this how i do
                Statement stmt1 = null;
                stmt1 = dbconn.createStatement();
                String insertQuery3 =........
                count = stmt9.executeUpdate(insertQuery3);
                try{
                  if ( stmt1!= null ){  stmt1.close();
                }
                else{
                System.out.println("No stm1 exist");
                }
                }catch(SQLException ex){   
                  System.out.println("SQLException has been caught for stmt1");
                  ex.printStackTrace(System.out);
                }
                ///For select we do this  
                Statement stmt2 = null;
                stmt2 = dbconn.createStatement(); 
                String selectQuery2= .........
                ResultSet rs2 = stmt2.executeQuery(selectQuery2);
                if(rs2.next())
                {
                }
                try{
                 if ( rs2!= null ){  
                     rs2.close();
                 }   else{
                 System.out.println("No rs2 exist");
                 }
                 if ( stmt2!= null ){ 
                      stmt2.close();
                 }   else{
                 System.out.println("No stm2 exist");
                 }
                }catch(SQLException ex)
                {   
                System.out.println("SQLException has been caught for stmt2");
                ex.printStackTrace(System.out);
                }
               dbconn.commit
            }
           catch (SQLException ex){
                ex.printStackTrace(System.out);
                try{  
              dbconn.rollback();
           }
           catch (Exception rollback){  
              rollback.printStackTrace(System.out);
              }
       }
       catch (Exception e){
           e.printStackTrace(System.out);
           try{  
              dbconn.rollback();
           }
           catch (Exception rollback){  
              rollback.printStackTrace(System.out);
             }
       }
       finally
     {
     }
        }
     catch (SocketTimeoutException ex){
           ex.printStackTrace();
     }
     catch (IOException ex){
           ex.printStackTrace();
     }
     catch (Exception ex){
           ex.printStackTrace(System.out);
     }    
      finally{
        try{
         if ( dbconn != null ){
           dbconn.close();
         }
         else{
          System.out.println("dbConn is null in finally close");
         }
        }
        catch(SQLException ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        try{
          if ( writeBuffer != null ){
            writeBuffer.close();
            //new changes added but no effect.
            readBuffer = null; 
            writeBuffer =null;
            receivedSocketConn1=null;
         }
         else{
          System.out.println("writeBuffer is null in finally close");
         }
        }
        catch(IOException ex){
            ex.printStackTrace(System.out);
        }
       }
      }
    }
```

Just to verify further I stripped down my codes to just have the socket application part and remove all other codes. Below is the jmap histo before any socket connection.

```
      num     #instances         #bytes  class name
    ----------------------------------------------
       1:          6023         824664  <methodKlass>
       2:          6023         726808  <constMethodKlass>
       3:           401         458376  <constantPoolKlass>
       4:           369         296320  <constantPoolCacheKlass>
       5:           401         293848  <instanceKlassKlass>
       6:           439         225264  [I
       7:          1512         165736  [C
       8:           772         144224  [B
       9:           461          56120  java.lang.Class
      10:           674          42880  [[I
      11:           602          39424  [S
      12:          1189          38048  java.lang.String
      13:            43          25112  <objArrayKlassKlass>
      14:           339          14896  [Ljava.lang.Object;
      15:             8           4672  <typeArrayKlassKlass>
      16:           112           3584  java.util.Hashtable$Entry
      17:            47           3384  java.lang.reflect.Field
      18:           132           3168  java.lang.StringBuilder
      19:            66           2352  [Ljava.lang.String;
      20:            25           2128  [Ljava.util.HashMap$Entry;
      21:            11           2112  <klassKlass>
      22:            38           1824  sun.util.locale.LocaleObjectCache$CacheEntry
      23:            28           1792  java.net.URL
      24:            74           1776  java.io.File
      25:            12           1760  [Ljava.util.Hashtable$Entry;
      26:            54           1728  java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap$HashEntry
      27:            48           1536  java.util.HashMap$Entry
      28:            36           1440  java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap$Segment
      29:            52           1408  [Ljava.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap$HashEntry;
      30:             3           1400  <methodDataKlass>
      31:            33           1320  java.lang.ref.Finalizer
      32:            16           1152  java.lang.reflect.Constructor
      33:            36           1152  java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock$NonfairSync
      34:            40            960  java.util.LinkedList$Node
      35:            24            960  java.util.LinkedHashMap$Entry
      36:            19            912  java.util.HashMap
      37:            20            800  sun.util.locale.BaseLocale$Key
      38:             9            720  [Ljava.util.WeakHashMap$Entry;
      39:            21            672  java.util.LinkedList
      40:            42            672  java.lang.Object
      41:            16            640  java.io.ObjectStreamField
      42:            16            640  java.lang.ref.SoftReference
      43:            32            632  [Ljava.lang.Class;
      44:             6            624  java.lang.Thread
      45:            19            608  sun.util.locale.BaseLocale
      46:            25            600  java.net.Parts
      47:            12            576  sun.misc.URLClassPath$JarLoader
      48:            22            528  sun.security.action.GetPropertyAction
      49:             6            480  java.util.jar.JarFile$JarFileEntry
      50:            20            480  java.io.ExpiringCache$Entry
      51:            20            480  java.util.Locale$LocaleKey
      52:             6            480  [Ljava.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap$Segment;
      53:            19            456  java.util.Locale
      54:            11            440  java.util.WeakHashMap$Entry
      55:             9            432  sun.nio.cs.UTF_8$Encoder
      56:             9            432  java.util.WeakHashMap
      57:             6            384  java.util.jar.JarFile
      58:             6            384  java.util.zip.ZipEntry
      59:             6            384  java.nio.DirectByteBuffer
      60:            12            384  java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue
      61:            16            384  java.lang.StringBuffer
      62:             6            336  java.util.zip.ZipFile$ZipFileInputStream
      63:             6            336  java.nio.DirectLongBufferU
      64:             6            336  java.util.zip.ZipFile$ZipFileInflaterInputStream
      65:            10            320  java.security.AccessControlContext
      66:            13            312  sun.misc.URLClassPath$3
      67:             6            288  java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap
      68:             8            256  java.util.Vector
      69:             8            256  java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
      70:             5            248  [Ljava.lang.reflect.Field;
      71:             2            224  java.net.SocksSocketImpl
      72:            14            224  java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock
      73:             8            208  [Ljava.io.ObjectStreamField;
      74:             8            192  [Ljava.lang.reflect.Constructor;
      75:             8            192  java.lang.Class$1
      76:             8            192  sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl
      77:             8            192  java.util.ArrayList
      78:             4            192  java.util.Hashtable
      79:             6            192  java.util.zip.Inflater
      80:             4            192  java.nio.HeapByteBuffer
      81:             6            192  java.util.zip.ZipCoder
      82:             4            192  java.nio.HeapCharBuffer
      83:             7            168  java.io.FileDescriptor
      84:             5            160  java.io.DataInputStream
      85:             2            160  java.lang.reflect.Method
      86:             6            144  sun.misc.MetaIndex
      87:             6            144  sun.misc.FileURLMapper
      88:             6            144  java.util.zip.ZStreamRef
      89:             6            144  java.util.ArrayDeque
      90:             6            144  sun.misc.PerfCounter
      91:             8            128  sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl
      92:             8            128  java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger
      93:             3            120  java.security.ProtectionDomain
      94:             3            120  sun.nio.cs.UTF_8$Decoder
      95:             2            112  java.util.LinkedHashMap
      96:             2            112  java.io.ExpiringCache$1
      97:             2            112  sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder
      98:             1            104  java.lang.ref.Reference$ReferenceHandler
      99:             1            104  java.lang.ref.Finalizer$FinalizerThread
     100:             1            104  sun.net.www.protocol.file.FileURLConnection
     101:             2             96  java.lang.ThreadGroup
     102:             3             96  java.util.Stack
     103:             2             96  java.io.BufferedReader
     104:             3             96  java.security.CodeSource
     105:             2             96  java.io.BufferedWriter
     106:             2             96  sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder
     107:             2             96  java.util.Properties
     108:             6             96  sun.misc.URLClassPath$JarLoader$1
     109:             3             96  java.io.FileInputStream
     110:             2             96  java.util.StringTokenizer
     111:             2             88  [Ljava.net.URL;
     112:             2             80  java.io.ExpiringCache
     113:             1             80  sun.misc.Launcher$ExtClassLoader
     114:             1             80  [Ljava.lang.ThreadLocal$ThreadLocalMap$Entry;
     115:             2             80  sun.misc.URLClassPath
     116:             5             80  java.lang.ThreadLocal
     117:             1             80  sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader
     118:             3             72  java.util.Collections$SynchronizedSet
     119:             3             72  java.lang.RuntimePermission
     120:             3             72  sun.misc.Signal
     121:             2             64  java.io.FileOutputStream
     122:             4             64  java.lang.Class$3
     123:             2             64  java.io.FilePermission
     124:             2             64  java.lang.VirtualMachineError
     125:             2             64  java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary
     126:             2             64  [Ljava.lang.Thread;
     127:             2             64  java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Null
     128:             2             64  java.lang.ThreadLocal$ThreadLocalMap$Entry
     129:             2             64  java.io.PrintStream
     130:             2             64  java.io.OutputStreamWriter
     131:             1             48  [J
     132:             2             48  java.net.InetAddress$Cache
     133:             2             48  java.net.InetAddress$Cache$Type
     134:             2             48  java.net.URLClassLoader$1
     135:             1             48  java.util.Hashtable$Enumerator
     136:             3             48  java.lang.ClassLoader$3
     137:             3             48  java.security.ProtectionDomain$Key
     138:             3             48  [Ljava.security.Principal;
     139:             3             48  java.lang.Integer
     140:             3             48  java.util.HashSet
     141:             3             48  sun.reflect.ReflectionFactory$GetReflectionFactoryAction
     142:             2             48  sun.misc.NativeSignalHandler
     143:             2             48  java.io.BufferedOutputStream
     144:             2             48  java.nio.charset.CoderResult
     145:             3             48  java.nio.charset.CodingErrorAction
     146:             2             48  [Ljava.io.File;
     147:             1             40  java.util.HashMap$EntryIterator
     148:             1             40  java.security.PrivilegedActionException
     149:             1             40  java.io.BufferedInputStream 
     154:             1             32  java.net.InetAddress     
     160:             1             32  java.lang.NoSuchMethodError 
     176:             1             32  java.net.Socket   
     193:             1             24  java.io.FileReader
     194:             1             24  java.net.Inet4AddressImpl
     195:             1             24  java.io.FilePermissionCollection
     196:             1             24  sun.util.locale.BaseLocale$Cache
     197:             1             24  java.lang.reflect.ReflectPermission
     198:             1             24  java.lang.ThreadLocal$ThreadLocalMap
     199:             1             24  java.util.BitSet
     200:             1             24  sun.net.sdp.SdpProvider
     201:             1             24  [Ljava.lang.reflect.Method;
     202:             1             24  java.net.InetSocketAddress
```

Jmap after closing 50 socket connections. Just compare this java.net.Socket can see a hike to 51.

```
  num     #instances         #bytes  class name
----------------------------------------------
   1:          7823        1070328  <methodKlass>
   2:          7823         983752  <constMethodKlass>
   3:          5717         971936  [C
   4:           536         635152  <constantPoolKlass>
   5:           495         413664  <constantPoolCacheKlass>
   6:           744         410336  [I
   7:           536         390976  <instanceKlassKlass>
   8:           711         255152  [B
   9:          2612          83584  java.lang.String
  10:           611          75240  java.lang.Class
  11:           832          58080  [S
  12:           876          54520  [[I
  13:            58          33872  <objArrayKlassKlass>
  14:          1218          29232  java.lang.StringBuilder
  15:            41          22576  <methodDataKlass>
  16:           350          17688  [Ljava.lang.Object;
  17:           269          12912  java.nio.HeapCharBuffer
  18:            41           5904  java.text.DecimalFormat
  19:            52           5824  java.net.SocksSocketImpl
  20:           310           4960  java.lang.Object
  21:             8           4672  <typeArrayKlassKlass>
  22:            40           4480  java.util.GregorianCalendar
  23:            40           3840  sun.util.calendar.Gregorian$Date
  24:            89           3832  [Ljava.lang.String;
  25:           117           3744  java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap$HashEntry
  26:           111           3552  java.util.HashMap$Entry
  27:            88           3520  java.lang.ref.Finalizer
  28:           109           3488  java.util.Hashtable$Entry
  29:             8           3200  commServer8000$ConnectionHandler
  30:            80           3200  java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap$Segment
  31:            39           3144  [Ljava.util.HashMap$Entry;
  32:            88           2816  java.lang.StackTraceElement
  33:            39           2808  java.lang.reflect.Field
  34:            41           2624  java.text.DecimalFormatSymbols
  35:            80           2560  java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock$NonfairSync
  36:            40           2560  java.text.SimpleDateFormat
  37:            50           2400  java.net.SocketInputStream
  38:            37           2368  java.net.URL
  39:            42           2352  sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfo
  40:            32           2304  java.lang.reflect.Constructor
  41:            80           2304  [Ljava.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap$HashEntry;
  42:             3           2120  [J
  43:            11           2112  <klassKlass>
  44:           128           2048  java.lang.Character
  45:            41           1968  sun.util.locale.LocaleObjectCache$CacheEntry
  46:            41           1640  java.text.DigitList
  47:            51           1632  java.net.Inet4Address
  48:            51           1632  java.net.Socket
  49:            40           1600  [Z
  50:            40           1600  java.util.LinkedHashMap$Entry
  51:            19           1520  [Ljava.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap$Segment;
  52:            31           1488  java.util.HashMap
  53:            61           1464  java.io.FileDescriptor
  54:            14           1456  java.lang.Thread
  55:             8           1088  [Ljava.util.Hashtable$Entry;
  56:            43           1032  java.util.LinkedList$Node
  57:            63           1008  java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger
  58:            25           1000  java.lang.ref.SoftReference
  59:            40            960  java.util.Date
  60:            19            912  java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap
  61:            18            864  java.nio.HeapByteBuffer
  62:            21            840  sun.util.locale.BaseLocale$Key
  63:            17            816  sun.nio.cs.UTF_8$Encoder
  64:            17            816  sun.misc.URLClassPath$JarLoader
  65:            32            768  java.io.ExpiringCache$Entry
  66:             9            720  [Ljava.util.WeakHashMap$Entry;
  67:            22            704  java.util.LinkedList
  68:            21            672  sun.util.locale.BaseLocale
  69:            16            640  java.io.ObjectStreamField
  70:            18            576  java.security.AccessControlContext
  71:            10            560  sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder
  72:            10            544  [Ljava.lang.StackTraceElement;
  73:             1            528  [Ljava.lang.Character; 
  85:             8            384  java.io.BufferedReader
  86:             6            384  java.nio.DirectByteBuffer
  87:             8            384  sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder
  88:             8            384  java.net.SocketOutputStream
  89:             9            360  sun.nio.cs.UTF_8$Decoder
  90:             6            336  java.util.LinkedHashMap    
  94:             6            336  java.util.zip.ZipFile$ZipFileInflaterInputStream
  95:             8            320  java.net.SocketTimeoutException
  96:            10            320  java.io.OutputStreamWriter
  97:             8            320  java.util.IdentityHashMap
  98:            13            312  java.io.File
  99:            18            296  [Ljava.lang.Class;
 100:            12            288  sun.misc.MetaIndex
 101:             6            288  java.util.Hashtable
 102:            17            272  java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock
 103:             8            256  java.net.InetAddress
 104:             8            256  java.util.Vector
 105:            16            256  sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl
 106:             8            256  java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
 107:             5            248  [Ljava.lang.reflect.Field;
 108:             6            240  java.util.WeakHashMap$Entry
 109:             7            224  java.util.ResourceBundle$LoaderReference
 110:             7            224  java.io.FileInputStream
 111:             9            216  java.util.ArrayList
 112:             9            216  java.util.Collections$SetFromMap
 113:             8            208  [Ljava.io.ObjectStreamField;
 114:             2            192  [Ljava.text.DateFormat$Field;
 115:             8            192  java.math.RoundingMode
 116:             8            192  java.io.InputStreamReader
 117:             6            192  java.util.zip.Inflater
 118:             6            192  java.util.zip.ZipCoder
 119:             8            192  [Ljava.security.ProtectionDomain;
 120:             7            168  sun.security.action.GetPropertyAction
 121:             4            160  java.security.ProtectionDomain
 122:            10            160  java.lang.Integer
 123:             2            160  [Ljava.lang.ThreadLocal$ThreadLocalMap$Entry;
 124:             4            160  java.util.Collections$SingletonMap
 125:             6            144  java.util.zip.ZStreamRef
 126:             6            144  java.util.ArrayDeque
 127:             6            144  sun.misc.PerfCounter
 128:             4            128  java.util.Stack
 129:             4            128  java.security.CodeSource
 130:             4            128  sun.util.LocaleServiceProviderPool
 131:             8            128  java.lang.Throwable$WrappedPrintStream
 132:             8            128  java.util.IdentityHashMap$KeySet
 133:             3            120  sun.misc.URLClassPath
 134:             2            112  java.io.ExpiringCache$1
 135:             7            112  java.net.Socket$3
 136:             7            112  java.net.Socket$2
 137:             7            112  java.lang.ThreadLocal
 138:             1            104  java.lang.ref.Reference$ReferenceHandler
 139:             1            104  java.lang.ref.Finalizer$FinalizerThread
 140:             2             96  java.lang.ThreadGroup
 141:             4             96  java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableRandomAccessList
 142:             3             96  java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary
 143:             2             96  java.util.Properties
 144:             3             96  java.lang.ThreadLocal$ThreadLocalMap$Entry
 145:             2             80  java.io.ExpiringCache
 146:             2             80  java.util.Locale$Category
 147:             1             80  sun.misc.Launcher$ExtClassLoader
 148:             1             80  sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader
 149:             1             80  java.lang.reflect.Method
 150:             3             72  java.util.Collections$SynchronizedSet
 151:             3             72  java.lang.RuntimePermission
 152:             3             72  sun.misc.Signal
 153:             3             72  java.util.Arrays$ArrayList
 154:             2             64  java.io.FileOutputStream
 155:             1             64  java.util.ResourceBundle$RBClassLoader
 156:             2             64  java.lang.VirtualMachineError
 157:             4             64  java.security.ProtectionDomain$Key
 158:             4             64  [Ljava.security.Principal;
 159:             2             64  [Ljava.lang.Thread;
 160:             4             64  java.util.LinkedHashSet
 161:             2             64  java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Null
 162:             2             64  sun.nio.fs.UnixPath
 163:             2             64  java.io.PrintStream
 164:             2             64  sun.util.locale.UnicodeLocaleExtension
 165:             1             56  java.text.DateFormatSymbols
 166:             3             48  java.text.AttributedCharacterIterator$Attribute
 167:             2             48  java.net.InetAddress$Cache
 168:             2             48  java.net.InetAddress$Cache$Type
 169:             1             48  [Ljava.math.RoundingMode;
 170:             2             48  sun.util.locale.LocaleExtensions
 171:             3             48  java.util.HashSet
 172:             2             48  java.lang.ThreadLocal$ThreadLocalMap
 173:             2             48  sun.misc.NativeSignalHandler
 174:             3             48  sun.net.www.protocol.jar.Handler
 175:             2             48  java.io.BufferedOutputStream
 176:             2             48  java.nio.charset.CoderResult
 177:             3             48  java.nio.charset.CodingErrorAction
 178:             1             40  java.util.ResourceBundle$1
 179:             1             40  java.io.BufferedInputStream
 180:             1             40  sun.text.resources.FormatData
 181:             1             40  sun.text.resources.FormatData_en
 182:             1             40  sun.text.resources.FormatData_en_US
 183:             1             40  sun.util.resources.CurrencyNames
 184:             1             40  sun.misc.Cleaner
 185:             1             40  sun.util.resources.CurrencyNames_en_US
 186:             1             40  sun.nio.cs.StandardCharsets$Aliases
 187:             1             40  sun.util.resources.CalendarData
 188:             1             40  sun.util.resources.CalendarData_en
 189:             1             40  sun.nio.cs.StandardCharsets$Classes
 190:             1             40  sun.nio.cs.StandardCharsets$Cache
 214:             1             24  sun.nio.cs.US_ASCII
 215:             1             24  sun.nio.cs.ISO_8859_1
 216:             1             24  java.net.Inet6AddressImpl
 217:             1             24  sun.nio.fs.NativeBuffer$Deallocator
 218:             1             24  sun.nio.cs.UTF_16BE
 219:             1             24  sun.nio.cs.UTF_16LE
 220:             1             24  java.util.Locale$Cache
 221:             1             24  sun.nio.cs.UTF_16
 222:             1             24  java.io.FilePermissionCollection
 223:             1             24  sun.util.locale.BaseLocale$Cache
 224:             1             24  java.lang.reflect.ReflectPermission
 225:             1             24  java.util.BitSet
 226:             1             24  sun.net.sdp.SdpProvider
 227:             1             24  [Ljava.lang.reflect.Method;
 228:             1             24  sun.misc.JarIndex
 229:             1             24  java.net.ServerSocket
```

Comment: Code is incomplete. Where are the readBuffer and writeBuffer initialized? Where are you closing the socket if they weren't initialized?

Comment: @EJP that is just a snippet of my codes. If you see  at the very top I have define this BufferedWriter writeBuffer = null;   and BufferedReader readBuffer = null; just below my function void run() { and in the finally section I have this if ( writeBuffer != null ){
writeBuffer.close();} hope its clear now.

Comment: No, it isn't clear. Where are they initialized to non-null values? *Are* they initialized to non-null values? You haven't answered my question about closing the socket at all.

Comment: Here is how its initilaze to non-null values writeBuffer =  new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(receivedSocketConn1.getOutputStream())); and         readBuffer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(receivedSocketConn1.getInputStream()));. For the socket I thought the logic says wen it comes into the run() function there is a big try and below is a catch and in the finally we  decide if socket have some value(initialized) or not initialized? Is that wrong? Beside closing the socket must I reinitialized it to null ?

Comment: @EJP I even tried this in the finally part if ( writeBuffer  != null) { writeBuffer .close(); readBuffer  = null;              writeBuffer =null;receivedSocketConn1=null;} still is the same too.
            
          }

Comment: I can't read code posted in comments. Edit it into your question. The part after the code is just an incomprehensible jumble.

Comment: @EJP as per suggestion I have added those in my question and commented it as //new changes added but no effect. Yes the part after code is the jmap histogram results of the number of instances.

Comment: You need to close all your `ResultSets,` `Statements,` and `Connections` in `finally` blocks. Otherwise leaks can occur. You don't need to initialize things to null when you assign them on the very next line: you can do it all in one line. You don't need `stmnt1,2,3,4,...` unless you're using them all at the same time, which you aren't. Economize on all this.

Comment: Why even the socket connection I close in the finally blocks yet the instance keep increasing and not decreasing?I need help here on the resultset and statement. The problem is that I got many different select, insert and update. So all of this I am keep in one big try and catch so I can rollback. That is why the individual resultset and statement I close using the try and catch.

Comment: I don't have anything to add to what I've already said here. You don't need most of this, but you do need `finally` blocks.

Comment: @EJP what could it be that I am missing  in the finally block when I am closing the socket any thing extra ? I tried to initialize the buffer read,write and socket to null yet its same? What else can I do ? I am actually studying your advice in previous comment with regards to resultset probably will open a separate question on this easier.

Comment: @EJP any input on why the socket is still retain even its closed well in the finally block?